# Count the number of cells in one row who contain the same content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the number of cells (in one row) who contain the same content. Like:

```
A      |B        |C        |D       |E
item   | test1   | test2   | test3  | result
Apple1 | red     | red     | red    | 3
Apple2 | red     | green   | green  | 2
Apple3 | green   | red     | red    | 2
Apple4 | red     | red     | red    | 3
Apple5 | red     | red     | N.F    | 2
Apple6 | red     | N.F     | N.F    | 1
Apple7 | N.M     | N.M     | N.M    | 0
```

Actually, in my table, there are not always "red" or "green", so it could be a dicimal number or a `String` (like "red" or "green").

And besides, there is some tests haven't been well carried out. So there are also `Not Found` and `NO MESEUREMENT` inside. I want to ignore them because in the statistical analyse, I just want to make the 'good' answers count, but without the errors.

And to be more clearly, I want to know the number of the majority cells who have the same contents. Because there could have the 4th test and so on, so I can have more than 3 columns of results in one row.

I've tried with `IF` fucntion but because there could be different 'standard' answers (like in the example, sometimes is "red" sometimes it's "green"), so I didn't make it. So if you've some idea, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to want an array formula:

```
=MAX(COUNTIFS($B2:$D2,$B2:$D2,$B2:$D2,"<>N.F",$B2:$D2,"<>N.M"))
```

This will find the max count of those that match.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So put the formula in E2, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy down.

[image]

Comment: Oh excuse me, I've forgotten one problem, that there have also `NOT FOUND` and `NO MESEUREMENT` inside. So how can I ignore them? because I just want to know the number of "good" results but if there is an error I don't need them as my data.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry I didn't well think it over very well. If you've some idea please leave a comment thanks.

Comment: @Hiddenllyy Just an FYI, on this site it is considered bad form to change the question and criteria after receiving answers as it exposes those who already answered to down votes.  That being said, I have changed the formula to your needs.  Just remember to think through your problem before posting next time.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I'll pay attention next time!

Answer (score 0):

A further useful item:
To find out which item is the most common, use this entry in E2.  It's an array formula so press CTRL SHIFT ENTER after typing it.

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,MODE(MATCH(A2:D2,A2:D2,0)))
```

[image]

Can't take credit for the solution.  Used it before and found it here.

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/most-frequently-occurring-word.html

Comment: Oh excuse me @Ken , I've forgotten one problem, that there have also NOT FOUND and NO MESEUREMENT inside. So how can I ignore them? because I just want to know the number of "good" results but if there is an error I don't need them as my data. 
 
I've updated the question, sorry I didn't well think it over very well. If you've some idea please leave a comment thanks